# install ROS on ubuntu14.04.3, depends errors

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ros

when I tried to install ROS in a 64-bit Ubuntu14.04.3 following this [document](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu), some problems occurred.

After I configured my Ubuntu repositories to allow "restricted," "universe," and "multiverse,I did this:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xB01FA116
```

then I entered:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

I got errors:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
ros-indigo-desktop-full:i386 : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-indigo-perception:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-indigo-simulators:i386 but it is not going to be installed
unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed    
          Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

then I tried this to fix the depends:

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It did not work.

Then I tried this :

```
sudo apt-get install libsdformat1
```

Still errors,
I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
```

I got many errors about i386 like this:

```
-mesa-dev-lts-utopic:i386 : Depends: mesa-common-dev-lts-utopic:i386 (= 10.3.2-0ubuntu1~trusty2) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 (= 10.3.2-0ubuntu1~trusty2) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libdrm-dev:i386 (>= 2.4.52) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libx11-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libx11-xcb-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
```

I don't know why I got such errors, beacuse my ubuntu is 64 bit. What can I do next? Thanks.

And my second question is what is the different between ROS Indigo Igloo,ROS Jade Turtle and ROS Kinetic Kame, thanks.

Comment: You'd probably get better answers on [ubuntu.se].

Answer (score 1):

**ROS Kinetic Kame**  (latest), **ROS Jade Turtle** and **ROS Indigo Igloo** are different versions/distributions of ROS. Other distributions of ROS are:
ROS Hydro Medusa, ROS Groovy Galapagos, ROS Fuerte Turtle, ROS Electric Emys, ROS Diamondback, ROS C Turtle, ROS Box Turtle.

**ROS Indigo** is primarily targeted at **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**. Indigo supports releasing, documenting and integration testing of catkin-based packages only. Previously, rosbuild-based packages were used which are also supported in ROS Indigo.

**ROS jade Turtle** is primarily targeted at **Ubuntu 15.04** (Ubuntu LTS 14.04 Trusty also supported)

**ROS Kinetic Kame** is primarily targeted at **Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial)** (Ubuntu 15.10 Wily and Debian Jessie also supported)

Now since you're using **Ubuntu 14.04.3 64-bit**, it is recommended that you install **ROS Indigo**.

If you're using it on a virtual drive, you can also download a pre-installed ROS distribution in Ubuntu from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_ULD8CBaw26TEpqUG1McGs5aVU/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing the listed dependencies (in the tutorial you are following) :

> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev-lts-utopic
>   mesa-common-dev-lts-utopic libxatracker-dev-lts-utopic
>   libopenvg1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
>   libgles1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
>   libgbm-dev-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic

That should resolve your issues.

Comment: But the tutorial says `Do not install these packages if you are using 14.04, it will destroy your X server:`.

Comment: here' a [link](http://answers.ros.org/question/203610/ubuntu-14042-unmet-dependencies-similar-for-14043/) for better explanation, you're using 14.04.3 not 14.04 !